# getting the time of X minutes ago in C

Tags: c, time

I would like to print the current time and the time of 10 minutes ago, but I don't know how to generate a time_t of X minutes ago...

```
#include <time.h>

time_t current_time;
time_t tenMinutesAgo;

current_time = time(NULL);
tenMinutesAgo = ???;

printf("current time = %s, 10 minutes ago = %s\n",ctime(current_time),ctime(tenMinutesAgo));
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: 10 minutes is about how many seconds? Do you know how to do a subtraction? :-)

Comment: Wow. That simple huh :) Thanks! I'll update the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `time(NULL)` returns the time in seconds from the [epoch (usually the Unix epoch)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch) i.e. **00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970 (or 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z ISO 8601)**:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

time_t current_time;
time_t tenMinutesAgo;

int main() {
  char* c_time_string;
  current_time = time(NULL);
  tenMinutesAgo = current_time - 10*60;//the time 10 minutes ago is 10*60

  c_time_string = ctime(&tenMinutesAgo);//convert the time tenMinutesAgo into a string format in the local time format

  printf("The time 10 minutes ago in seconds from the epoch is: %i\n", (int)tenMinutesAgo);
  printf("The time 10 minutes ago from the epoch in the local time format is: %s\n", c_time_string);

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

@PaulGriffiths makes a good point in that my solution isn't guaranteed to be portable. If you want portability, then check his answer. **But**, if you're writing code on any of most popular OS flavors (*nix, Solaris, Windows), this solution will work.

Comment: Note that solution may not be portable, since the C standard doesn't require that `time_t` be measured in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is not guaranteed to be portable, since the C standard does not require that `time_t` be measured in seconds.

`time_t` is a real type, though, so you can do arithmetic on it, and this does give us a route to do it. You can set up two `struct tm`s a second apart:

```
struct tm first;
struct tm second;
time_t ts_first;
time_t ts_second;
double sec_diff;

first.tm_year = 100;
first.tm_mon = 0;
first.tm_mday = 2;
first.tm_hour = 1;
first.tm_minute = 20;
first.tm_second = 20;
first.tm_isdst = -1;

second.tm_year = 100;
second.tm_mon = 0;
second.tm_mday = 2;
second.tm_hour = 1;
second.tm_minute = 20;
second.tm_second = 21;
second.tm_isdst = -1;
```

turn them into `time_t` values:

```
ts_first = mktime(&first);
if ( ts_first == -1 ) {
    /* Do your error checking  */
}

ts_second = mktime(&second);
if ( ts_second == -1 ) {
    /* Do your error checking  */
}
```

call `difftime()` on them:

```
sec_diff = difftime(ts_second, ts_first);
```

and then you can multiply `sec_diff` by the number of seconds you want, and subtract that from the value returned by `time`.

Of course, if your available system time resolution is greater than one second, this won't work, and you could try changing the `tm_min` member instead since you're looking for minutes, but this'll be pretty unlikely.

Comment: I don't know about the C standard, but http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/time.html states "The time() function shall return the value of time in seconds since the Epoch.", and http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/types.h.html: "time_t: Used for time in seconds.". So the (currently) accepted solution looks quite portable to me.

Comment: @MartinR: It's fine if you don't need something entirely standard, and most modern desktop systems will implement it like that, but the C standand says "the range and precision of times representable in `clock_t` and `time_t` are implementation defined` in Section 7.27.1.4. C11 also has `timespec_get()` which may be helpful, too.